# How to deal with oracle database in android

Tags: java, android, database, oracle

I have to use oracle database in android.  
I have tried to work as usual java coding with oracle,but I have not succeed.  
I have used this java code.

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@:1521:XE","SYSTEM","pis");  
Statement s=con.createStatement();
s.executeUpdate("create table customer1(id int primary key,name varchar(20) not null,city varchar(20))");
s.close();
con.close();
```

I am new to android programming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you should be talking directly to the Oracle database from the device itself. Aside from anything else, the security aspect would almost certainly prove challenging. You normally want to keep your database network access pretty limited.

Usually you'd host a web service of some kind exposing business-meaningful operations, and that web service would talk to Oracle. The Android device would then talk to the web service (probably via REST, although I dare say SOAP *could* work).

Comment: Actually i want to deal with huge amount of data, so can SQLite is sufficient for it?

Comment: @MahiMali: Well that would be putting the data *on the device* which is an entirely different approach. Are you happy for each device to have the data separately? Would you need to work out synchronization, or would each device have a separate set of data? How large is a "huge amount of data"?

Comment: Yes each device have data separately.Huge means min 20lak records per year approx.

Comment: @MahiMali: It's worth bearing in mind the international audience of Stack Overflow - "laK" isn't widely used outside Southern Asia. 2 million records per year *might* be fine - it depends on the nature of the data, and what you want to do with it. I would strongly suggest you *try* using SQLite, populating it with a good sample of data.

Answer (score 1):

```
I have to use oracle database in android please help me.
```

AFAIK integrating Oracle into android is not possible as of now.What you can have is dump database on server and have your mobile talk to webserver to fetch data.Communication can be made via XML or JSON.

Comment: Use SQLite.Its inbuilt into Android

Comment: Actually i want to deal with huge amount of data with, so can SQLite is sufficient for it?

Comment: @MahiMali What is your problem ? Read the replies first before keep asking "Can I use SQLite". What huge database ? Are you going to have all indian population data in your database ?

Comment: @Makky: ya May be.but why should i tell you?

Answer (score 1):

Using Web Service instead. You don't want to expose database connection in your mobile app